# Apache ActiveMQ transfert duration

Tags: java, apache

i tried to estimate the transfert duration of a ActiveMQ communication between a sender and a receiver. I dont know how i can get my variables sending_time and reception_time at the same time, so that i could estimate  transfert_duration = reception_time - sending time.

Sender:

```html
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Sender {

    private ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private Destination destination = null;
    private MessageProducer producer = null;
    
    public long sending_time;
    
    public Sender() {

    }

    public void sendMessage() {

        try {
            factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            destination = session.createQueue("QUEUE");
            producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();

            message.setText("Hello");

            sending_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            producer.send(message);
            
            
            System.out.println("Sent : " + message.getText());

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
        Sender sender = new Sender();
        sender.sendMessage();
    }

}
```

Receiver:

```html
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class Receiver {
    private ConnectionFactory factory = null;
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Session session = null;
    private Destination destination = null;
    private MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    
    public long reception_time;

    public Receiver() {

    }

    public void receiveMessage() {
        try {
            factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory( "tcp://localhost:61616");
            connection = factory.createConnection();
            connection.start();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            destination = session.createQueue("QUEUE");
            consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
            
            System.out.println("Waiting for messages...");
            
            while( true ){
             
              Message message = consumer.receive();

                 
                 reception_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

          
                 if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                  
                     TextMessage text = (TextMessage) message;
                     
                     System.out.println("Received : " + text.getText());
                
                 }
            }
            
           
        } catch (JMSException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
        Receiver receiver = new Receiver();
        receiver.receiveMessage();
    }
}
```